# Changing desired date fetched from api end points

Tags: java

The transaction date which i fetch from open api is in this format: 20210412. I have to validate this with a date on the ui webpage whose format is 4/12/2021. I used substring method as below:

```
    actualtsDate = transactionDate.substring(5,6) + "/" + transactionDate.substring(6) + "/"
            + transactionDate.substring(0, 4);
```

This method clearly gives the desired output which is 4/12/2021 but If the date which fetch is 20211104, then this method doesn't work. Need a way out of this. Please suggest.

Note: Transaction date is: 20210412 and actualtsdate is 4/12/2021 where 12 is the day, 4 is the month and 2021 is the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing with substrings and such you should convert both date strings to `LocalDate` and then compare the two objects using `isEqual`

```
String fromApi = "20210412";
LocalDate apiDate = LocalDate.parse(fromApi, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
```

Then to compare this date to the UI date we use a DateTimeFormatter and formats the `apiDate` object to a String

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
String output = formatter.format(apiDate);

String fromUI = "4/12/2021";
System.out.println(fromUI.equals(output));
```

---

Old version

```
LocalDate uiDate = LocalDate.parse(fromUI, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"));
  
System.out.println(uiDate.isEqual(apiDate));
```